ffmpeg -- copy attached cover image (cover.jpg) of video file during encode?
I am trying to encode a video with ffmpeg which has a cover file attached. This cover file should end up in the encoded video as well.
I can do this with mkvextract attachments movie.mkv 1 && <long ffmpeg encode command> && mkvpropedit movie_new.mkv --add-attachment cover.jpg. Both old and new show up in mediainfo with the two lines
Cover                                    : Yes
Attachments                              : cover.jpg

But when I try to integrate this into a ffmpeg command, ffmpeg insists on detecting a second video stream and either dropping it or encoding it as a second video stream which completely confuses the player.
What I tried:
-map 0:t --> error, cannot find attachments; -map 0:t? --> runs and encodes second video stream
All kinds of -map combinations, even a test of attaching cover.jpg when a coverless movie_new.mkv is available, together with a separate cover.jpg and ffmpeg -i movie_new.mkv -i cover.jpg ... -map 1 -map 0 -c copy -disposition:0 attached_pic fails.
This seems to be a bug in ffmpeg at least up to 7.0.2 where an attachment with the correct MIME type according to IANA is mistakenly interpreted as a video stream.
During conversion attempts, the header of ffmpeg (or ffprobe in general) shows:
 Stream #0:7: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x360 [SAR 96:96 DAR 16:9], 90k tbr, 90k tbn (attached pic)
      Metadata:
        filename        : cover.jpg
        mimetype        : image/jpeg

It works for the example video made per @rotem's suggestion, there it's
 Stream #0:1: Attachment: none
      Metadata:
        filename        : cover.jpg
        mimetype        : image/jpg

but only because image/jpg isn't actually an existing MIME type.
The latter attachment works with -map 0:t, the former does not since no attachment is recognized.
Is this possible to work around within a ffmpeg command?
Other tools like mkvtoolnix-gui add the correct mime type and might have been used here for the original video, so setting a wrong mime type is not a valid workaround.

Try : ffmpeg -i movie.mkv -i cover.jpg -map 1 -map 0 -c copy -c:v:0 mjpeg -disposition:0 attached_pic OUT

Very good idea, but this was a test to see if I could get ffmpeg to make a cover attachment at all. The real situation is that the cover is already embedded in movie.mkv. How can I transfer that to movie_new.mkv so it doesn't end up as second video stream, but as an attachment of cover.jpg (mkvtoolnix too shows it as such in movie.mkv, this seems to be correct)?

Try creating reproducible example: ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i mandelbrot=s=128x128 -frames:v 1 -update 1 cover.jpg and ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=s=192x108:r=1:d=10 input.mkv and ffmpeg -y -i input.mkv -attach cover.jpg -map 0 -c copy -metadata:s:t mimetype="image/jpg" -metadata:s:t:0 filename=cover.jpg input_cover.mkv and ffmpeg -y -i input_cover.mkv -c:v libx264 -map 0:v -map 0:t output_cover.mkv. I think that -map 0:t is working...

I can get your example to work (progress!), and with ffmpeg -i input_cover.mkv -c:v copy -map 0 -map 0:t output_cover.mkv, I can also copy the cover as attachment over. If there's an extra -c:t copy, I end up with the cover added twice. I am trying this with the full-scale command and the real video, but I need a few hours since I am not at this machine at the moment.

@Rotem: See my edit in the question. I added additional information why it's not working.

What is the original codec and what codec are you trying to convert to?

Original codec of the video is MPEG Video Version 2, Main@High profile (BluRay). Codec ID: V_MPEG2. Conversion to H.264 AVC High@L5 profile, Codec ID V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC
How does this play a role?

@Rotem: This seems to work only because mimetype="image/jpg" is actually an illegal mimetype, the correct one according to https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#image is image/jpeg.
When I try this with the actual mimetype, your example fails as well. This seems to be a bug in ffmpeg where an attachment is mistakenly identified as a video.

@emk2203 depending of the codec the way you attach thumbnail may be different

Now the issue is reproducible, but I can't find a good solution (the issue could be a bug or a missing feature). The only solution I can think of is extracting the cover image to a temporary file: ffmpeg -y -i input_cover.mkv -map 0:v:1 -c copy -update 1 tmp.jpg, and attach it to the output in a second execution of FFmpeg: ffmpeg -y -i input_cover.mkv -attach tmp.jpg -map 0:v:0 -c:v libx264 -metadata:s:t mimetype="image/jpeg" -metadata:s:t:0 filename=cover.jpg output_cover.mkv. I know it's not very helpful...

The suggestion is probably the way I go. Thanks. Do you have a suggestion for getting rid of all attachments with ffmpeg? I'd like to have this attachment gone because if it stays in and gets converted, it blocks the playback (at least with mpv). This should probably be a separate question, though.
